# Should domain model be intelligent or there must be services, which operate it?

Tags: object-oriented, php, domain-model, factory

I'm building a web-app for a licensing service. My domain models are Licenses, and they can be of two types at the moment: server and client license. They are almost same, except server license has *softwareId* field, and client license has *hardwareIdArray* (client licenses can be registered to multiple clients).

So, I have a base model **License** with it's children: **ClientLicense** and **ServerLicense**, which bring additional fields.

Models of each type are fetched by respective Repositories (I'm using TYPO3 Extbase framework, where it is standard and recommended way).

Now comes the interesting part: each license has some additional info, which I can't persist (well, I can, but only in temp cache), but instead should fetch it from REST service (e.g. "expirationDate", which may be changed outside of my web-app). And for each type of license this additional info may be different and may be fetched by different method in REST api. Also each license type has different *activate()* REST method. At same time there are common REST methods, like *getLicenseFile()*.

So, I decided to hide all this internal stuff under **LicenseService** class, which is recommended to communicate by Controllers or other classes, that need some license info. **LicenseService** itself communicates to **LicenseRestApi**, which contains some low-level functionality to perform REST requests.

And here comes a question: who should know about each license type specific functionality? F.e. when a controller asks a service to *getAllLicenses($user)*, is it a Service, who should determine a type of license and then perform calls to respective Repository and appropriate methods in RestApi; or a license should know everything about itself and call RestApi; or some new classes, like **ClientLicenseProcessor** and **ServerLicenseProcessor**, to which should LicenseService communicate and all the communication with RestApi should be within these *processors*, so in this case LicenseService will act as FactoryMethod for creating appropriate processor?

My goal is to hold specific type logic in one place and not spread it between several classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service shouldn't make any decisions or you end up with a [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Your license aggregate should make the decisions. If the license aggregate needs to call a web service you pass an instance of a helper for that service to the method on the aggregate. It can them choose to use them if it so wishes.

Comment: So, basicaly **ClientLicense->activate(LicenseApi $licenseApi)** is the correct way to do this? And when I want to fetch all licenses (server and client as well) should I call generic *LicenseRepository*, which should return me not *License*, but *ClientLicense* and *ServerLicense* objects?

Comment: Normally you would have two repositories for the two types of licenses but other than that it sounds reasonable.

Comment: Domain Driven Design embodies to s philosophy if you like buzz words.